# SVG Upload to WordPress Issue

Tags: svg

So I added this code to my Functions.php file and all of a sudden I can upload SVG's across my entire server, all my clients websites.

I know there are security disclaimers regarding using this code.

```
function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
 $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
 return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
```

Anyone have any idea why this is possible for all my clients and not just the one website I put the code onto? Is this something I should be worried about?

Comment: I don't understand your question: First you say it's working for all clients, and then it's not? Please clarify. And welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange!

Comment: Yes, I'm new here! Thank you. I edited the question a bit. I just don't understand how I added the code to one website and now all of the sudden I can upload SVG's on every one of my websites across my server.

Comment: Are your client's sites part of a multisite with your site?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Maybe they are all using the same theme directory. Otherwise it can't happen.

Comment: Hmm, I do use the same Theme across all the websites. But, I have removed the function from the functions.php file. Yet, I can still upload SVGs across all the websites.

Answer (score 0):

I've established this is a plugin/theme conflict. I will report back when I know more.

I tested this on a couple of my other client's websites that are on different servers but share similar themes/plugins, and sure enough, I can upload SVGs.